# Auth0 example webpack parsing error

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, auth0

I'm trying to set up my first vue.js 2 app with Auth0. The API part works fine, but I'm getting errors in webpack related to the auth service described in the auth0 quickstart here: https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/vuejs

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (18:8)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|   }
|
|   auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({
```

I don't really understand the syntax being used in this class, since auth0 is the name used in the import statement. My application is a standard vue.js scaffold generated app with webpack.

Here is the whole .js from the quickstart:

```
import auth0 from 'auth0-js'
import { AUTH_CONFIG } from './auth0-variables'
import EventEmitter from 'eventemitter3'
import router from './../router'

export default class AuthService {

  constructor () {
    this.login = this.login.bind(this)
    this.setSession = this.setSession.bind(this)
    this.logout = this.logout.bind(this)
    this.isAuthenticated = this.isAuthenticated.bind(this)
  }

  auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({
    domain: 'omitted',
    clientID: 'omitted',
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000/callback',
    audience: 'omitted',
    responseType: 'token id_token',
    scope: 'openid'
  })

  login () {
    this.auth0.authorize()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Turns out the auth0 examples are not compatible with the most recent vue version. 
This github repo seemed to do the trick for me: 
https://github.com/DominikAngerer/auth0-vue